# Easiest way to find the element is present in ENUM or not in JAVA?

Tags: java, enums

I need to find the specific string element is present in **ENUM** or not at runtime using *java* and based on that take action. What is the efficient way to do so.

Comment: No, you don't. As a compiled language, you should already know what's in your `enum`. There is no guess work. What are you trying to _actually do_ that makes you think you need to reverse lookup an `enum`?

Comment: Yes, I know it's not possible, but there are other ways using that I can do the same task, but I want efficient way to do the same.

Comment: Cool: *What are you trying to actually do that makes you think you need to reverse lookup an `enum`*?

Comment: This is probably an x/y problem

Answer (score 2):

A very minimal example given your requirements.  Here is some documentation for Enums that you should look at as well. [Enum info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-)

Given the enum below:

```
enum TestEnum {
    FOO, 
    BAR
}
```

You could simply call valueOf to determine if the String is a valid for that enum.

```
public boolean exampleTest(final String value) {
   try {
      TestEnum.valueOf(value);
      return true;
   } catch (final IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException) {
      // Log if desired
      return false;
   }
}
```

Note: Enum#valueOf is case sensitive so the String argument must match exactly.

```
exampleTest(“FOO”); // true
exampleTest(null); // false
exampleTest(“BAR”); // true
exampleTest(“bar”); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below -

```
public enum Direction {
   NORTH("North"),
   EAST("East"),
   SOUTH("South"),
   WEST("West")

    private String dir;

    Direction(String dir) {
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    public String getDir() {
        return dir;
    }
}
```

to check with specific string you can do like below -

```
for(Direction dir : Direction.values())
{
//check your condition here
    System.out.println(dir.name() + " :: "+ env.getDir());
}
```